Logic gate of frequency based computing
Given input and output that has constant amplitude and with only two states frequency: Low freq (0) and high freq (1).
Suppose the oscilator wave shape of both input or output is simple sine wave.

Define NOT operator that outputting 1 if input is 0, otherwise 0.
Define AND operator that outputting 1 if both input are 1, otherwise 0.
Similar to NAND, XOR, OR, NOR, XNOR, IMPLY and NIMPLY that accepts two inputs and resulting one output.

